# Can't calculate the values of html input type range

Tags: javascript

I would like to calculate the values of Html Range Inputs.
Just want the result to be dynamically changed when the input range change.
The function I write is not clear enough and seems didn't work.
Can anyone can help me please.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my html code:

```
<form>
 Height:
 <input type="range" id="height" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="0"     max="200" step="0.1" value="0" />
 <br>
 Weight:
 <input type="range" id="weight" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="0"    max="200" step="0.1" value="0" />
 <br>
</form>
<div id="displaybmi"> Your BMI : </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
function(){
        var height, weight;
        height = $('#height').value;
        weight = $('#weight').value;

        function calbmi(weight,height){
                         bmi = weight/(height*height);
        }   
       document.getElementByID('displaybmi').innerHTML = calbmi(weight,height);
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/wm81/935fnmyx/4/

Comment: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById` and `.value` should be `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 problems in your code and 1 inconsistency.

1) jQuery uses the function `val()` to get the value of an input, not the property `value`

change:

```
height = $('#height').value;
weight = $('#weight').value;
```

to

```
height = $('#height').val();
weight = $('#weight').val();
```

2) Javascript is case-sensitive, and does not have a function `document.getElementByID` it is `document.getElementById` (lowercase "d")

3) Your code is executed once, when the page loads, you need it to execute every time one of your `input` fields changes. To do this the code should be inside a jQuery `$(document).ready()` function.

4) You method which calculates bmi does not return any value, it just sets a variable (`bmi`) equal to the result. You wanted to return this value so as to use it to output into html.

The inconstancy is that you use jQuery to get the fields by Id, but then revert to vanilla javascript for the output, you could make that

```
$('#displaybmi').html(calbmi(weight,height));
```

Of course, there's nothing wrong with using the native javascript call, it just might be easier for you to stick with one way or the other.

---

Some other observations:

- You dont need this bit at all: `onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);"`
- You should enforce that the fields have only numbers entered, as you are doing mathematical operations on them. Consider using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) like

  `height = parseFloat($('#height').val())`

---

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/935fnmyx/8/

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. I have changed the code still it's not calculating..           var height, weight;
   height = parseFloat($('#height').val());
   weight = parseFloat($('#height').val()); 

    ( ($("#height")||("#weight")).change(function(e) {    
          
            $('#displaybmi').html(calbmi(weight,height)); 
        
          function calbmi(){
    
   var bmi = weight/(height*height);
            return bmi;
             
  } 
   
    
}));

Answer (score -2):

getElementById, not ByID.  Don't capitalise the last character.